# InDesign: one line (horizontal) bullet list

Tags: adobe-indesign

I would like to create a single line (no carriage return) bullet list with items delimited by blank space (tab width or configured), is this possible with InDesign?

Right now I am using a dirty method:

- Bullet character (Alt+8)
- Non-breaking space (Ctrl+Alt+X)
- Text
- Five non-breaking spaces (Ctrl+Alt+X)
- Next bullet list item

[image: >>> This is what it should look like <<<]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using the bulleted list functionality.  However, if you are trying to create a line of bulleted items that is spaced evenly across the text box, you can do that using the "flush space" character.

If you want your bullet and text to remain together, you would insert the bullet character, a space (of whatever width you prefer), the text and then a flush space.  Repeat this until you have all of your bulleted items listed on your line. Do not add the flush space to the last item. Make sure that the line is set to fully justified.

InDesign will determine the width for each of the flush spaces so that each of the bulleted items are spaced evenly across the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it, courtesy of English Wikipedia:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        li {
            margin: 0;
            display: inline;
        }
        li:before {
            content: " · ";
            font-weight: bold
        }
        ul {
            list-style-type: disc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```